# What phase do I use for my task?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I want to run a task to copy environment specific properties before I package my WAR file.  Below is my task.

```
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <tasks>
                                                            <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.properties"/>
                                                            <copy file="src/main/resources/${env}_environment.properties"
                                                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.properties" />
                                                            <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/${env}_hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
                                                            <copy file="src/main/resources/${env}_hibernate.cfg.xml"
                                                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
                                                            <echo message="Copied ${env}_hibernate.cfg.xml properties. " />
                                                    </tasks>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

However, when start up my app, invoking a goal from my Tomcat profile, by running "mvn -P tomcat tomcat:run", the above task doesn't get run.  Any ideas how I can correct this?  The Tomcat profile I include is below. - Dave

```
            <profile>
                    <id>tomcat</id>
                    <activation>
                            <property>
                                    <name>env</name>
                                    <value>dev</value>
                            </property>
                    </activation>
                    <build>
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.1</version>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                                                    <path>/leadsmonitor</path>
                                                    <server>nnadbmon-tomcat</server>
                                                    <update>true</update>
                                                    <url>http://nnadbmon.mydomain.com:8080/manager</url>
                                                    <warFile>target/leadsmonitor.war</warFile>
                                                    <systemProperties>
                                                            <JAVA_OPTS>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=6 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -verbose:gc"</JAVA_OPTS>
                                                    </systemProperties>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                    </build>
            </profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach it to the `compile` phase. This will actually get executed ***after*** the compilation has finished.

Comment: Attach what to the compile phase?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the ant-run-plugin. That should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The maven-antrun-plugin runs at prepare-package so you can add that to your command:

```
mvn -P tomcat tomcat:run prepare-package
```

Comment: Is there some way that I can configure within my pom.xml to automatically execute prepare-package when I run "mvn -P tomcat tomcat:run"?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [tomcat:run](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html),

`tomcat:run` Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase *compile* prior to executing itself.

`prepare-package` phase comes later - before `package`

Perhaps you should try [tomcat:run-war](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html).

`tomcat:run-war` Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase *package* prior to executing itself.